# KafkaListener Losing messages

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm working on an event sourcing application that manage orders. 
I have a consumer which is a spring-boot micro-service containing a listener like this :

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "mytopic", groupId = "mygroup")
    public void listenMyTopic(ConsumerRecord<?, String> record) {
        log.info("Starting processing ack {}", record.value());
        readReturnMessage(record, false);
    }
```

Some (not all) messages are sent to my topic but not listened by my listener (I didn't found them in my logs).

I'm sure that my messages are sent because I can consume them with terminal consumer.

Do have an idea of the cause of those lost messages ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I am not aware of any such issues. What versions are you using?

Comment: Is there a separate application using `groupId = "mygroup"` that would be getting some messages?

Comment: @GaryRussell Spring-boot 2.0.0 and Spring-Kafka 2.1.0

Comment: @cricket_007 there is no other application using the same groupId

Comment: Those versions are very old. Boot 2.0 is [end of life](https://spring.io/blog/2019/02/15/spring-boot-2-1-3-available-now). The latest Boot 2.0.x release was 2.0.9. The last Kafka 2.1.x release is 2.1.13. You should consider upgrading to the latest Boot 2.1.x or 2.2.0 release. But I seriously doubt the framework is dropping messages. Please provide some evidence (edit the question - don't try to add it in a comment).

Comment: The problem was that there was a POSTPROD environment that consumes Kafka events on the PROD topics.
The team that did this did not think to inform the other teams.